# How to create directory with cUrl, ssl?

Tags: php, curl, ftp

Im creating secure FTP manager on php. I have the following:

```
curl_setopt(self::$FTP, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://".$user.":".$pass."@".$host);
curl_setopt(self::$FTP, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt(self::$FTP, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt(self::$FTP, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
curl_setopt(self::$FTP, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, TRUE);
curl_setopt(self::$FTP, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_exec(self::$FTP);
```

its ok. Now how to create directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the:

`CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS` as `TRUE`

to create missing directories when an FTP operation encounters a path that currently doesn't exist.

**You can read this on the documentation:** [PHP curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)